# @JsonTypeInfo with Spring Data Rest results in serialization error

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink, spring-data-rest

I am currently trying a scenario with `EclipseLink`, `spring-data-jpa` and `spring-data-rest` where I have `Embeddable` classes with inheritance.

The scenario is rather simple: A `Parent` contains a value that can ether be a `PercentageValue` or an `AbsoluteValue`.

The mapping:
The `Parent` holds an embeddable value:

```java
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Embedded
    private Value value;
}
```

`Value` is the abstract superclass for the different values

```java
@Embeddable
@Customizer(Customizers.ValueCustomizer.class)
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @Type(name="PERCENTAGE", value=PercentageValue.class),
        @Type(name="ABSOLUTE", value=AbsoluteValue.class)})
public abstract class Value {}
```

`PercentageValue` is an example for a concrete Value implementation

```java
@Embeddable
@Customizer(Customizers.PercentageValueCustomizer.class)
@JsonSerialize(as = PercentageValue.class)
public class PercentageValue extends Value {
    private BigDecimal percentageValue;
}
```

Using EclipseLink customizers I can get the inheritance with embeddables to work but spring-data-rest does not seem to be able to serialize the value objects because of the type information.

A `GET`request on the parents resource results in the following exception:

`.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: Type id handling not implemented for type java.lang.Object (by serializer of type org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$NestedEntitySerializer) (through reference chain: org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.["content"]->com.example.Parent["value"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Type id handling not implemented for type java.lang.Object (by serializer of type org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$NestedEntitySerializer) (through reference chain: org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.["content"]->com.example.Parent["value"])`

It seems that `NestedEntitySerializer` is not implementing `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer#serializeWithType` falling back to the standard implementation that just throws an exception.

If I remove the `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation the serialization works but of course the `POST` fails because Jackson is lacking the type information for proper deserialization.

Any thoughts on that? Is there a way to make the serialization work with `JsonTypeInfo`?

The complete project is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/mduesterhoeft/EclipseLink-embeddable-generic-test).

Comment: The same problem occurs in a plain entity scenario: https://github.com/mduesterhoeft/spring-data-rest-entity-inheritance https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-872

Comment: This is fixed in the meantime and it works at least with `@JsonTypeInfo` with `include=JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY`

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data REST has a number of documented limitations when it comes to supporting Jackson's `@JsonTypeInfo` when serializing data to the REST output.

Currently, it appears that `@JsonTypeInfo(include=JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY)` works ([spring-data-rest#1242](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/issues/1242)), but the other `JsonTypeInfo.As` types do not ([spring-data-rest#1269](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/issues/1269)).

It should be possible to migrate your model to use `JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY` instead of `JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY`.